# What is the difference between two methods of creation linked list in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

what the difference between methods *push()* and *add()* since this ones do the same stuff - push the value into linked list via constructor, but *add()* doesn't add the value

```
public class LinkedList {
 
    static class Node {
        int value;
        Node next;
        Node(int value){
            this.value = value;
            next = null;      }
    }; 
    Node head;
    Node next;     
    void push(Node node){
        Node newnode = node;
        newnode.next = head;
        head = newnode;     }     
    void add(Node node, Node head){addNode(node,head);} 
    void addNode(Node node, Node head){     
        Node newnode = node;
        newnode.next = head;
        head = newnode;     }     
    /* Function to print linked list */
    void printlist(Node head){                 
          while(head != null){
              System.out.println(head.value + " ");
              head = head.next; }    
              }
 
    // Driver program to test above functions
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.head = null;
        list.head = new Node(5);
        list.push(new Node(6));
        list.add(new Node(3), list.head); 
        list.push(new Node(7));        
        list.printlist(list.head);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through your `add` method with the debugger. Think about what the name `head` actually refers to.

Comment: And of course https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *add* method, or more correctly, *addNode* method, is not doing anything to the instance.

It is effectively assigning the parameter *head* to, the *next* value of parameter, *node*.

```java
void addNode(Node node, Node head) {
    node.next = head;
}
```

The *push* method is correct, it will stack the object before the instance's *head* node.

You can remove the the *addNode* method, and for the *add* method, it only requires 1 parameter.

You'll want to locate the last node in the structure, and then append the parameter to it.

```java
void add(Node node) {
    Node lastNode = this.head;
    while (lastNode.next != null) lastNode = lastNode.next;
    lastNode.next = node;
}
```

Comment: I think the question refers to the OP's own implementation.

Comment: @demsee, I misread that, the answer is relevant now.

Comment: But the actual problem, I think, was that the OP didn't notice that their `head` parameter hid their `head` field.